# Rails 5.2 SQLite boolean column fails when represent_boolean_as_integer is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `promoted` boolean column on my model. Since upgrading to Rails 5.2 and adopting the new `represent_boolean_as_integer = true` default for SQLite, one of the specs is failing.

The is one model created:

```
MyModel.first.promoted # => false
```

When `represent_boolean_as_integer = true` then the query does not work and the spec fails:

```
MyModel.where(promoted: false).count # => 0
MyModel.where(promoted: true).count # => 0
```

The SQL uses `promoted = 1` as expected.

When `represent_boolean_as_integer = false` the query works and the spec passes:

```
MyModel.where(promoted: false).count # => 1
MyModel.where(promoted: true).count # => 0
```

The SQL uses `promoted = 't'` as expected.

Since this is the new default I'd like to adopt it.

I have tried regenerating the test database.

- Rails 5.2.3
- SQLite 1.4.1

Comment: Same here, using rails 5.2.3 and SQLite 1.4.2. When i add Rails.application.config.active_record.sqlite3.represent_boolean_as_integer = false to application.rb it works.